# How can i change wpf datagrid Cell color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, material-design

[image]

I Use Material Design UI for wpf.
in Datagrid, i selected Row 2.
when my mouse focus lost on Row 2, then Cells Colors become like Picture.
I want to set that color, but i don't know how to change that color.

```
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Editable}" Value="False" >
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#777777"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#555555" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CCCCCC" />
        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

this is my Code for that UI

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#555555"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CCCCCC"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!-- Add more triggers or setters here -->
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: I already do this Code. but it doesn't work.